# How To Wait on Another Element to Become Available in Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I am trying to download files from the Front-End of a database Web Application called Skyward...it' super ancient. However, I have somewhat nailed down the process. I was curious if there was a way for Python Selenium to account for a button that is present, then when the new button becomes available press the button. The biggest issue is processing times are different and I have no way to calculate them.

When I click on Export a processing Window opens up and looks like this:
[image]

Once the Button is Available it will look like this:
[image]

Here is the element for the `My Print Queue`:

```html
<a class="button" id="printMsgBtn1" tabindex="5" href="javascript:if (cbs('printMsgBtn1')) {vQPSetup.cancelCheckQueue(); closeMessage(false, 'dPrintMessage'); openMyPrintQueue(); cancelEvent();}" role="button">My Print Queue</a>
```

The process that clicks on the above is this:

```py
# Click on id="browsetool_export"
# Opens Options to Download Report
# XPATH = //*[@id='browsetool_export']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='browsetool_export']")))
element.click();

# Click on .xlsx Radio Button
# XPATH = //*[@id='ExCOptXLSX']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ExCOptXLSX']")))
element.click();

# Click on Export Button 
# XPATH  = //*[@id='bExport']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='bExport']")))
element.click();
time.sleep(20)

# Click on Download Export Button
# XPATH = //*[@id='printMsgBtn1']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='printMsgBtn1']")))
element.click();
time.sleep(2)
```

1. How can I account for the times more dynamically?
2. How can I have the code hit the `Download Export File` button once the export has finished processing making the `My Print Queue` button is no longer available?

How can I account for that, when

Comment: You could use wait for the text Export Data: Secured User to be visible and click the Download Export File. Wait also is pretty dynamic as it does it by increments.

Comment: @arundeepchohan how could I go about doing that?

Comment: @arundeepchohan I tried `element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "printMsgBtn1"), "Download Export File"))
element.click();` but it didn't seem to work

Comment: element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    BC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Download Export 
    File')]"))).click()

Comment: What about this one?

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the timeout issuse: `  File ".\export_secured_users_list_report.py", line 159, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Download Export File')]"))).click()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: How long is the run time on the processing request?

Comment: it varies from 10-43 seconds

Comment: This is why I wanted to take a more dynamic approach to wait on a specific element to appear.

Comment: wait generally uses 500ms increments to get an element so if you just used a larger time it should still be very accurate. So instead of 20 use like 50 or something

Comment: If you knew the downloading speed and size you could put a number otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes finding the best selector or wait type can be hard. I suggest using Selenium IDE. See here as well

[Problem Selecting Okay Button with Python and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982025/problem-selecting-okay-button-with-python-and-selenium/63212291#63212291)